How to Share Total Screen Time from DeviceActivityReportExtension/DeviceActivityMonitor to App?
Since it has been few days we are working on Apple screen time api for one of our app where we are able to get screen time successfully using DeviceActivityReport Extension in the extension itself. We have add FamilyControl familypicker selection for app selections. But We have functionality like where user can create a squad and share screen time within members of squad same like as
Jomo.
So we want to get only total screen time in our app side. I have attached a screenshot for reference of JOMO App below.
Key questions:

Is there a feasible way to share total screen time data from the DeviceActivityReport Extension to the app?
Can DeviceActivity Monitor be used to achieve this goal? If so, how?
Are there alternative approaches to consider for sharing total screen time between the extension and app?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!


Apple does not allow access the only way I have heard of this happening is by creating your own Screen time with a VPN, you block apps/websites by cutting the internet connection and keep track of time by seeing what app is making web calls.

@loremipsum How is JOMO app achieving this? I believe they are using screen time api. Can you please install above app? and check that how it works and let me know your thoughts!!

There is a zero percent chance I will be doing that.
